# Create Image from DensityPlot monitor rendering problem

Tags: plotting

I want to create a large `DensityPlot` in a way that it outputs to a separate notebook in a second monitor attached to my computer desktop. The delivered output image is not smooth. Here is the code and look the jagged lines.  Output `DensityPlot` image

```
DensityPlot[Sin[2 Pi*x - Pi], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ImageSize -> {2500, 1500}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> (Lighter[Black, #] &), Mesh -> 30]
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding the option PlotPoints -> 100 -- this gets rid of much of the blockiness.

Comment: Please add answer to credit you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is not due to the second monitor, but to the graphic itself. The apparent low resolution of the image can be fixed by adding the option

```
PlotPoints -> 100
```

to the plot  command (you may wish to experiment with the exact value).